# Good lower-bound for $\inf_{x \in \Delta_n} \|Gx\|$ where $G$ is an $N \times n$ random matrix with iid entries from $\mathcal N(0,1/\sqrt{N})$

Tags: pr.probability, random-matrices, measure-concentration, compressed-sensing

Let $G$ be an $N \times n$ random matrix with independent entries distributed according to a centered Gaussian with variance $1/\sqrt{N}$ and let $n/N = \lambda \in (0, 1)$. Let $\Delta_n$ be the $(n-1)$-dimensional probability simplex.

> **Question.** What is a good lower-bound for $\inf_{x \in \Delta_n}\|Gx\|_2$ which is valid w.p $1-o(1)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\Delta_n$?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Does using an estimate of the smallest singular value suffice for you? Alternatively, a possible argument could go through epsilon nets. I haven't checked the calculations but I think the size of an epsilon net of $\Delta_n$ has size roughly $n^{1/\epsilon^2}$ (upto some constants in both the parameters) which isnt that large.

Comment: Yes, an epsilon-net argument should be able to give something down the line.  In any, case my  problem seems to be completely solved by Theorem II of this monograph https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.09433.pdf